# Not recognising "In file included from"

Tags: quickfix, errorformat

I'm using the default `errorformat`, but messages starting with "In file included from" aren't giving me the quickfix output I expect

For example:

```
|| [  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/blah/FooBar.cpp.o
|| In file included from /Users/me/Projects/FooTron9000/repo/src/FooBar.cpp:8:
/Users/me/Projects/FooTron9000/repo/src/FooHeader.h|5 col 10| fatal error: 'DoesNotExist.h' file not found                                                                                                                              
|| #include "DoesNotExist.h"
||          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|| 1 error generated.
```

I actually want to be able to jump to line 8 of /Users/me/Projects/FooTron9000/repo/src/FooBar.cpp, not just line 5 of FooHeader.h. How can I set that up?

Comment: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Errorformats

Comment: `:h :compiler` to choose one of predefined patterns

Comment: @MaximKim Yup, read that before posting. Still stuck. I think there might be some default errorformats in there which are deliberately excluding the lines I want, but I can't work out how to get rid of them. `errorformat-=blahblahblah` in my vimrc isn't doing it.

Comment: @Matt Tried that. No luck. The gcc compiler format specifically seems to want to exclude those lines (also I think I'm using Clang (XCode)? Not sure if it has the same output, but I think so).

Comment: you have to build errorformat that handles it for you. Examples are in the link I have provided earlier. `:h errorformat` also has examples.

Comment: @MaximKim the solution is to rebuild one from scratch? Really? :/

Comment: @Len yes (take the one you have as a base, tune it). But if you find another solution, I will be glad to know it too.

Answer (score 1):

```
let &efm .= ',%+GIn file included from %f:%l%*[\,:]'
```

The command `let &efm .= ',Z'`  appends `,Z` to `'errorformat'` (abbr. `'efm'`).

Here, `%+G`  means use the whole string as message. It is used instead of `%m`.